# setting emacs default Frame issue

Tags: emacs, frame

Trying to set a custom Frame size using .emacs file. However when I open emacs, it goes to that size then immediately defaults back to the standard smaller Frame.

Is this just a live with bug, or is there something that overrides the .emacs file after the .emacs file is read.

here is my current .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (wheatgrass)))
 '(global-linum-mode t)
 '(line-number-mode t)
 '(show-paren-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
)

(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 52))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 140))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you.  I put your config in a file and did `emacs -q -l custominit.el` and it did the right thing.  Try looking at `initial-frame-alist` and your Xresources.

Comment: Emacs 25 (which is almost ready for general public release) and the master branch both contain significant bug fixes for frame size and placement, including, but not limited to exact pixel frame sizes at the time of creation.  In any event, the default settings of the current version of Emacs 24.5 combined with **only** the settings in the question above should not cause the behavior described.